# jQuery keyup event does not set event.shiftKey

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to listen to the shift key being pressed and released again using jQuery.

See JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/669QT/)

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'shift down<br>';
    }
});
$(document).bind('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'shift up<br>';
    }
});
```

The keyup/keydown events seem to be called properly in general. However, if shift is the only button being pressed then `event.shiftKey` is only set for the keyDOWN event, not for the keyUP event. You can see that in the JSFiddle the "key up" message is never printed in this case. However, if I press shift + something else (e.g. Ctrl) everything works like it should.

Is this a bug in jQuery? Any workarounds?

Comment: `event.shiftKey` indicates that the shift key is down, it wouldn't make much sense if it was still true after releasing the shift key ?

Comment: Ah, I assumed .shiftKey means "this event is associated with the shift key". If it actually means "the key is down right now" then this does indeed make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it indicates wether or not the shift key is currently down to distinguish shift+key combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ardeneo mentioned in his comment I was misunderstanding the .shiftKey property. The correct way seems to be to listen to both keyup and keydown and then just check for event.shiftKey to see whether it was pressed or lifted.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/669QT/2/)

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 16) {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'shift down<br>';
    }
});
$(document).bind('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 16) {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'shift up<br>';
    }
});
```

checking the keycode works .. but event.shiftkey does not seems to work in keyup

Comment: When you key up the shift the shiftKey is false because is not pressed anymore. The var show the current status and not if it's the key or not.

Answer (score 2):

USE it  $(document).bind('keyup keydown', function(e){shifted = e.shiftKey} );

Answer (score 2):

e.shiftKey has a bug, I tried it. Does not work (My guess maybe on older instances) 
Whereas e.which === 16 works perfectly fine.

```
          self.on("keyup", ""+id, function(e) {
                if (e.which === 16) {
                    console.log(e.which);
                    // Your Code :)
                }
          }
```

Comment: Why it's a bug? When you key up the shift the shiftKey is false because is not pressed anymore